# unlimited user input lists to empty list

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists.
**list_1** is like this:

```
["car",2500],["secondCar",2000], ...
```

**list_2** is empty.

I have sample menu output for user for option 1,2,3 etc

If user picks **option 1** I retrieve it from **list_1** and **add** to **list_2** by doing :

```
list_2.append(list_1[1])
```

My problem is I want to keep asking user for input. Once they're done selecting option 1, I ask for input again and they can either select option 1 or 2 or 3 until the terminate option is selected I want keep getting inputs

this is python 3 btw

Comment: Could you post your relevent code here? Could you post a sample of your input, output and desired output? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use infinite loop.

you need to adapt your code like this

when user chooses a stop option **break** will stop and exit infinite loop

`lst=[]
while True:
    inp=input("enter some words: ")
    if inp == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        lst.append(inp)`